# Amazon CloudFront TTFB and download time increases progressively during the page load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

Running some tests with CloudFront (Pull CDN mode) I'm getting increasing TTFB and download time during the same web page load. The image bellow depicts the situation.

If I access any of those images individually they load much faster.

Do you have any idea why this may happen?

[image]

Comment: Have you ever found the cause here?